# matrix of objects' array properties

Tags: matlab

I have an array of classes (we'll call it `a`, size Mx1) that contains a property (`feature`) which holds a 1xN array. I'm trying to get a new matrix that is MxN which contains rows of each of the `feature` property of the objects.  For example:

```
M = 3
N = 4
a(1,1).feature = [1 2 3 4]
a(2,1).feature = [5 6 7 8]
a(3,1).feature = [9 10 11 12]
```

then, given some function, the answer would end up as:

```
ans = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 9 10 11 12]
```

Currently, I've been using the following:

```
ans = cell2mat({a.feature}')
```

however I feel there should be a way to do this without having to convert to a cell, switch the dimensions, and then convert to a matrix.  Am I correct or would this be the best way to solve the issue?  I haven't been able to find any such function in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have an array of objects and you access a property using dot referencing, a [comma separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) is returned. This comma separated list [can be passed to a function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html#br2js35-13) and will appear as multiple input arguments.

In your case, you can pass this comma separated list to [`cat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) and specify that you want each value to be concatenated to the next along the first dimension. So this would simply become:

```
features = cat(1, a.feature)

%// 1     2     3     4
%// 5     6     7     8
%// 9    10    11    12
```

This is functionally equivalent to:

```
features = cat(1, a(1).feature, a(2).feature, a(3).feature, ..., a(end).feature);
```